# Cannot drag an item below the last item using jquery-ui-sortable

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

I have `<div>`s that I can drag from parent `<div>` **A** to parent `<div>` **B** or within the `<div>`s in `<div>` **B**.

When the final `<div>` in **B** is occupied, I cannot drag a `<div>` from **A** into **B** to be the last `<div>` in **B**.

```js
$(function() {

  $(".Layout-Target").sortable({
    connectWith: ".Layout-Target"
  }).disableSelection();

  $("#sortable1").sortable({
    connectWith: ".Layout-Target"
  }).disableSelection();

});
```

```css
#sortable1,
#sortable2 {
  border: 1px solid #eee;
  width: 142px;
  min-height: 20px;
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 5px 0 0 0;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 10px;
  height: 1000px;
}

#sortable2 div {
  margin: 0 5px 5px 5px;
  padding: 5px;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  width: 120px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://resources/demos/style.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>


<div id="sortable1">
  <div class="ui-state-default">1</div>
  <div class="ui-state-default">2</div>
  <div class="ui-state-default">3</div>
  <div class="ui-state-default">4</div>
</div>

<div id="sortable2" class="Layout-Target">
  <div class="ui-state-highlight Layout-Target">Item 1</div>
  <div class="ui-state-highlight Layout-Target">Item 2</div>
  <div class="ui-state-highlight Layout-Target">Item 3</div>
  <div class="ui-state-highlight Layout-Target">Item 4</div>
  <div class="ui-state-highlight Layout-Target">Item 5
    <div class="ui-state-default">5</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I.e. I cannot drag a `<div>` below 'Item 5'. But if I move the element 5 inside 'Item 5' away, I can drag something below 'Item 5'.

Please let me know if you need more clarity.